# PostgreSQL and filtered recursive query

Tags: oracle, postgresql, filtering, recursive-query

There is an ability to query tree in Oracle with clauses `CONNECT BY` and `START WITH`.

For example:

```
SELECT RPAD (' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 4) || node_name AS node, LEVEL
  FROM hierarchy
  START WITH NVL (pig_ear_id, 0) = 0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = pig_ear_id;
```

The query result can be simply filtered to show the only nodes which accepted by filter predicate or located on the path to root:

```
SELECT RPAD (' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 4) || node_name AS node, LEVEL
  FROM hierarchy
  START WITH NVL (pig_ear_id, 0) = 0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = pig_ear_id AND id IN (
                 SELECT id
                   FROM hierarchy
                   START WITH node_name = 'some-pattern'
                   CONNECT BY PRIOR pig_ear_id = id
               );
```

A similar select in PostgreSQL will be built with clause `WITH RECURSIVE ...`. As I understand one with-query can not be included in other with-query to get same filtered result as Oracle allows.

How to rewrite the second select in PostgreSQL?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *As I understand one with-query can not be included in other with-query*

Of course you can, just write one after the other:

```
with recursive valid_nodes as (

   -- this is the inner "CONNECT BY" query from your example
   select id 
   from hierarchy
   where node_name = 'some-pattern'
   union all
   select c.id
   from hierarchy c
     join valid_nodes p on c.id = p.pig_ear_id

), final_tree as (

   -- this is outer query from your example

   select node_name as node, 1 as level
   from hierarchy
   where NVL (pig_ear_id, 0) = 0

   union all

   select c.node_name, p.level + 1
   from hierarchy c
     join final_tree p on p.id = c.pig_ear_id
   where id in (select id from valid_nodes) -- and here we re-use the previous CTE

)
select rpad(node, level - 1)||node, level
from final_tree;
```

Note the `recursive` keyword only needs to be stated at the beginning. Regardless on how many recursive CTEs you have (but you need to have at least one in the CTE chain, *if* you use it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a with query that is calling some function and that function in turn has a with query,
then it allows us and not raise any error...in that way we still able to have nested with query.

so typically i created a query using with clause. see the first query below.
It has in clause which has select query that is selecting records returned by the functions(my_function).
and the function has another hierarchical with query.

Also i do not know what you want to return from your query.so change query as u need.This is just the way to achieve required structure.

Below is the syntax for sql server.Change appropriately for any other database.

```
with alias_list
(
pig_ear_id,
node_name,
id
) as (
select pig_ear_id, node_name, id
  from hierarchy
 where pig_ear_id = ?
union all
select b.pig_ear_id, node_name, id
  from alias_list a, hierarchy b
 where a.pig_ear_id = b.id
   and id in (select id from my_function('some-pattern')))
select * from alias_list;
```

==============================================================

```
create function my_function(@node_name   varchar(40))
returns @temptable table
(
   id varchar(40)
)
as
begin

with alias_list
(
pig_ear_id,
node_name,
id
) as (
select pig_ear_id, node_name, id
  from hierarchy
 where node_name = ?
union all
select b.pig_ear_id, node_name, id
  from alias_list a, hierarchy b
 where a.id = b.pig_ear_id)

insert into @temptable select * from alias_list;
return
end
```

================================================================

Comment: No need for a function. CTEs (aka "with queries") _can_ be nested (actually: chained)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , agreed